# Is there a way to select a key by using a string?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using the Nebular Angular theme. when my object is returned in the object ServerDataSource, you have to supply a key to get that string. However, in my 
case, an object is returned and I need to try and select that string by selecting first the object and then the string.

I've already tried solutions such as "dataKey: 'data.page.maximum'" and so on.

```
        this.tableBulkProductsOverviewRemoteSource = new ServerDataSource(this.httpClient, {
            endPoint: 'URL',
            dataKey: 'data',
            totalKey: 'data.page.total',
            pagerPageKey: ''
        });
```

In the total key, I am trying to get the object and then the string via a string.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Object.keys(yourobject) will return an array of properties an object has.  You can then reference them with yourobject[keyname].  To get the first property: yourobject(Object.keys(yourobject)[0])

Comment: Can you paste exact code for better understanding.